# Фокус на элемент формы при её создании

Tags: c#, winforms

На форме есть 2 TextBox, 2 Label и Button. При открытии формы выделяется текст в первом TextBox и меняется цвет рамки. Как это отменить?

Comment: Можно в Loaded формы явно указать фокус на другом элементе - `element.Focus()` метод, если память не обманывает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Экспериментально выяснилось, что установка свойства **TabStop = false** контрола отключает подсветку рамочкой, но и запрещает переключение фокуса на этот контрол клавишей таб. Если такое поведение допустимо, то можно считать решением.

Если переключение по таб важно (обычно важно), то имеет смысл руками задать порядок переключения контролов таб-ом с помощью свойства **TabIndex** у всех имеющихся контролов. По умолчанию значения **TabIndex** назначаются автоинкрементом в порядке добавления контолов на форму, если собирать форму коннструктором, и при открытии окна фокус и подсветка появляются у контрола с **TabIndex = 0**.

Comment: Не плохое решение. Я переключил фокус на Label `label1.Focus();`, так как Label нет визуального эффекта фокуса.